# Drop Downlist direction in AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocomplete

I have a problem with an Auto-complete textview.I have the Auto-complete textview on the bottom
  of the screen, and when i add adapter in it and then run this code then it show drop-down in 
  upward direction. so please help me to show the drop down of Auto-complete textview in downward 
  direction and helper must appreciate.

Answer (score -1):

I too had the same problem.

In `AutoCompleteTextView` in xml file add this line:

```
android:dropDownHeight="100dp"
```